# Javascript to check if PWA or Mobile Web

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I was curious if anyone knew a javascript based method for detecting whether the web experience was being run as a PWA (progressive web app) or it was simply being run as a standard mobile website (with full browser UI).

Is there any difference between a PWA that is "installed" versus one that isn't but still has the service worker and/or app cache registered?

Comment: That distinction is somewhat murky, since both are fundamentally built using the same technologies. What exactly do you want to detect?

Comment: @deceze basically, whether or not it's been installed via as a legit PWA or if it's just running like a standard site. I'm not all that familiar with service workers and caches but I'm guessing that you can register both without something legitimately being installed as a PWA (like on a phone). Maybe the best way to check is whether the browser UI is visible but I'm not sure if that's accessible via JS.

Comment: Similar to this but for android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653024/check-if-web-app-is-added-to-home-screen-on-android/

Comment: Is there any way visually to differentiate between PWA vs Mobile Web ?

Comment: @vikramvi Depends on the PWA's app manifest. If it's set to run with `display-mode: browser`, then it is visually the same as your web browser. However many PWAs use `standalone`, `minimal-ui` or `fullscreen`, which are visually different.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If this is for analytical purposes you could set the start URL in the manifest file to include a query string parameter, ex:

```
"start_url": "./?mode=standalone"
```

Then in your JavaScript you are able to check for this query string parameter.

---

#### Update (2020-08-19)

Pete LePage wrote a blog on how to setup a custom dimension in Google Analytics using the code below which checks the display mode using `window.matchMedia`:

```
let displayMode = 'browser';
  const mqStandAlone = '(display-mode: standalone)';
  if (navigator.standalone || window.matchMedia(mqStandAlone).matches) {
    displayMode = 'standalone';
  }
ga('set', 'dimension1', displayMode);
```

Read more: https://petelepage.com/blog/2020/08/measure-understand-how-installed-pwa-users-differ-from-browser-tab-users/

#### Update (2017-01-20):

Alternatively you could check in JavaScript using:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  console.log("This is running as standalone.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is helpful. If this isn't possible, because of company politics (or other issues), can you think of any other way to differentiate the two?

Comment: Updated my original answer, you are able to check in JavaScript using:

    ```window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches```

Comment: In case of setting `start_url` how will you detect this in JS code whethere  app is running on which mode ?

Comment: @PardeepJain you are able to check the query string, (ex: `location.search.indexOf("mode"))`

Comment: @KevinFarrugia Will this check only work on the "start url" (start screen) or is it always there no matter on what route you are using the app?

Comment: @AlexeiS. the JavaScript check will work on any page.

Comment: If you want to support Firefox on Android the query component is still the way to go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode#browser_compatibility

Comment: A caveat with checking standalone display-mode is that the user can toggle back and forth between standalone mode and browser mode.  This is true at least for Chrome.  You basically have to check it every time you fire analytics unless you're only checking once for user engagement.

Answer (score 52):

**Edit 11 Oct 2019:** Added an extra switch to check if the app is launched via TWA - document.referrer.includes('android-app://')

**This works for all - TWA, Chrome & Safari:**

```
const isInStandaloneMode = () =>
      (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) || (window.navigator.standalone) || document.referrer.includes('android-app://');

 if (isInStandaloneMode()) {
    console.log("webapp is installed")
}
```

Comment: since it it probably wont change, wouldn't it make sense to just make it a variable instead of a function

Comment: Yes, I agree. Do you know if that would give any minor performance benefits?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping it as is since it became pretty complex already. And, functions are the simplest way to encapsulate things. Saving one entry in a call stack during function call is negligible.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if the PWA has been added and started by Firefox on Android

Comment: There seems to be a bug in FF which prevents the matchMedia approach to work: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285858#c29

Comment: This doesn't always work.  If your PWA is set to fullscreen, display-mode will be fullscreen instead of standalone, and testing for that wouldn't be correct since the browser might just be set to fullscreen by the user.

Answer (score 25):

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  console.log("This is running as standalone.");
}
```

This answer is correct but it's worth to mention that PWA could run on plenty of display modes:

- fullscreen
- standalone
- minimal-ui
- browser

If you run your PWA in a 'fullscreen' mode it will return `false` so additional checks are necessary like:

```
function isPwa() {
    return ["fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui"].some(
        (displayMode) => window.matchMedia('(display-mode: ' + displayMode + ')').matches
    );
}
```

Note that `window.matchMedia` check will return `true` for the 'browser' display mode even when it's not an installed PWA app.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped...
I re-wrote it like this: 

`function isPwa() {
    var displayModes = ["fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui"];
    return displayModes.some((displayMode) => window.matchMedia('(display-mode: ' + displayMode + ')').matches);
}`

Comment: Good answer, but it also passes the check of isPwa() when we make spa build instead of pwa and run it in full-screen mode. I wanna check if a user is using it in installed mode. Anyway to check that?

Answer (score 1):

**Progressive enhancement** is more a concept than an specific function or method that involves several technologies. Now progressive web apps are base on **service workers** which you can verify if the browser support it.

```
// Check for browser support of service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
```

Project [lighthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse) can help you to detect whether an application is **progressive enhanced** by performing evaluations of several technologies. Take a look on it.

[image]

Hope this help, to clarify.

Comment: I guess I should specify. This is for analytics purposes so I want to know if there is a way to tell with Javascript whether someone is currently viewing the PWA version of the site or the regular version. I was thinking maybe checking to see if the service worker is registered but couldn't it be registered even on mobile web if the site hasn't been "installed"?

Answer (score -4):

In my PWA, created with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, following statement works:

```
var isPWA = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSAppHost/i);
```