# next-pwa is not working and there is no error in production

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-pwa

The repo is open source

```js
// next.config.js
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    sw: '/sw.js'
  },
});
```

[_document.js](https://github.com/ats1999/time-stamp/blob/main/pages/_document.js)

[_app.js](https://github.com/ats1999/time-stamp/blob/main/pages/_app.js)

### Live

https://time-stamp.vercel.app

I have checked weather the PWA is working on the above URL or not using

```js
function isPwa() {
    return ["fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui"].some(
        (displayMode) => window.matchMedia('(display-mode: ' + displayMode + ')').matches
    );
}
isPwa() // false
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742390/javascript-to-check-if-pwa-or-mobile-web
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `next-pwa` package like this :

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const runtimeCaching = require("next-pwa/cache");

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    runtimeCaching,
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  }
});
```

Comment: Still its not working

Answer (score 0):

updating the next-pwa and following the steps in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585089/build-error-when-compiling-next-js-app-using-next-pwa`
worked for me

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34019981)