# Build error when compiling Next.js app using next-pwa

Tags: javascript, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I have been trying to run a local Next.js (v 12.2.2) project but for some reason, the dev script is not working as it should.
All the dependencies have been installed but still, I can't narrow down the reason why the script doesn't work.

The terminal looks like this after running the script

[image]

> error - Please check your GenerateSW plugin configuration:
> [WebpackGenerateSW] 'reactStrictMode' property is not expected to be
> here. Did you mean property 'exclude'?

Here's the `next.config.js` file

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack5: true,
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
        return config;
    },
    pwa: {
        dest: "public",
        register: true,
        disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    },
    images: {
        domains: ["pbs.twimg.com", "img.icons8.com", "gateway.moralisipfs.com", "ipfs.moralis.io", "lh3.googleusercontent.com", "www.artnews.com"],
    },
    // for running with docker
    output: "standalone",
});
```

Here's the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "musixverse-client",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.6",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.7.8",
    "@web3auth/web3auth": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "magic-sdk": "^8.0.1",
    "moralis": "^1.10.0",
    "next": "^12.2.2",
    "next-pwa": "^5.4.4",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.1.16",
    "next-themes": "^0.0.15",
    "persona": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.6.12",
    "react-moralis": "^1.4.0",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web3": "^1.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

node-version: 16.17.0,
npm-version: 8.19.0

Comment: It says: "dude, reactStrictMode is not allowed here - read the dooooocs", do somthing, try to delete reactStrictMode

Comment: @gapsf no luck buddy...
It keeps throwing errors for all the consecutive properties defined in next.config.js. I read the docs exhaustively but got nothing from it, that's why I asked the question : )

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction check syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your usage of the `next-pwa` plugin is incorrect as of version 5.6.0. A breaking change was introduced that changed the plugin signature (see [next-pwa/releases/tag/5.6.0](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/releases/tag/5.6.0)).

> Start from version `5.6.0`. This plugin function signature has been
> changed to follow the recommended pattern from `next.js`. Mainly
> extracting `pwa` config from mixing into rest of the next.js config.

From version 5.6.0, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa#configuration), your config should look like the following.

```js
// `next-pwa` config should be passed here
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
});

// Use `withPWA` and pass general Next.js config
module.exports = withPWA({    
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack5: true,
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
        return config;
    },
    images: {
        domains: ["pbs.twimg.com", "img.icons8.com", "gateway.moralisipfs.com", "ipfs.moralis.io", "lh3.googleusercontent.com", "www.artnews.com"]
    },
    output: "standalone"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the above configuration but getting the below error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://mydomain.or/_next/static/TtNoj27ce4xV1zZzFfm_C/_buildManifest.js","status":404}]
```

Comment: Here's a [link](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/issues/288) to a similar issue faced by someone raised on github. Try excluding buildManifest.js in next.config