# Checking through safari whether the PWA is added to homescreen

Tags: ios, homescreen, progressive-web-apps

So I have coded myself a way to display the pop-up encouragement to add the app to home screen on iOS for PWA. OK, user does it, when he clicks through the app all is good. However, when he returns to the website, I want to check whether the app has already been added to the home screen. I have found only this so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986409/6470918
This states that basically it is impossible. Did this situation change during the last two years?

Thank you in advance,

Grzegorz

Comment: Did you managed to find something for this problem.

Comment: Hi, yes, did you find any solution?

Comment: The solution from your linked stackoverlow thread uses the shared `localStorage` on the Chrome and the PWA app.
However on iOS the `localStorage` between Safari and a PWA is not shared. [This article](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/how-to-share-session-cookie-or-state-between-pwa-in-standalone-mode-and-safari-on-ios) tries to solve this issue with the shared Cache content.